# AngularJS - ng-click does not remove previous click's modifications when clicked again

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-service, angularjs-ng-include, angularjs-ng-click

So I am trying to acomplish this example: http://jsfiddle.net/pkozlowski_opensource/WXJ3p/15/

However, for some reason, when I click on one div, and then on another, it does not remove the "active" class from the previous div so it highlights both , hence all my divs end up with the class active if I click all of them. I want to make it to where it will actually remove the class if I click anywhere else on the body and also if I click on any other div, like the fiddle example.

**My jsFIddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/GeorgiAngelov/jUj56/4/

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
          <button class="addQuestionButton btn btn-primary" ng-click="AddRootQuestion(questions)">Add node</button>
        <div ng-repeat="question in questions" ng-include="question">     </div>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="question">
    <!-- Single question starts here -->
        <div ng-controller="QuestionController" ng-class="{active : isSelected(question)}">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="AddSubQuestion(question)">Add node</button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click = "editQuestion(question)">Edit Question</button>
        </div>
        <div ng-repeat="question in question.nodes" ng-include="question">
        </div>                      
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: can you make plunkr for this?

Comment: I just added jsFiddle to my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since each single question has its own `QuestionController`, and `QuestionController`is where `$scope.selected` is being set, they don't interact with each other. That is to say, when you click edit, it sets `selected` *for that individual controller*.

The easy way to fix it would be to set a property on a *parent* scope (the containing controller) when clicking edit:

```javascript
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.questions = [];  

    $scope.AddRootQuestion = function(questions) {
        questions.push({name: 'Question', nodes: []});
    };

    // added this method --v
    $scope.setSelected = function(q) {
        $scope.selected = q;
    };
}

function QuestionController($scope) {
    $scope.choices = [];
    $scope.choice = {text: ''};

    $scope.AddSubQuestion = function(question, $element) {
      var newName = 'Name of question goes here';
      question.nodes.push({name: newName, id: 'it goes in here', nodes: []});
    };

    // modified this method --v
    $scope.editQuestion = function(question){
      $scope.setSelected(question);
    };

    $scope.isSelected = function(question) {
      return $scope.selected === question;
    };
}
```

But this makes `QuestionController` dependent upon a parent controller. A much better design would be to move all the data and data manipulation methods into a service:

```javascript
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.factory('Question', function() {
  return {
    questions: [],

    addRootQuestion: function() {
      this.questions.push({name: 'Question', nodes: []});
    },

    addSubQuestion: function(question, data) {
      question.nodes.push(data);
    },

    setSelectedQuestion: function(question) {
      this.selectedQuestion = question;
    },

    isSelectedQuestion: function(question) {
      return this.selectedQuestion == question;
    }
  };
});
```

You can then inject the service into your controllers:

```javascript
function MyCtrl($scope, Question) {
  $scope.questions = Question.questions;  

  $scope.AddRootQuestion = function() {
    Question.addRootQuestion();
  };
}

function QuestionController($scope, Question) {
  $scope.choices = [];
  $scope.choice = {text: ''};

  $scope.AddSubQuestion = function(question, $element) {
    var newName = 'Name of question goes here';
    Question.addSubQuestion(question, {
      name: newName, id: 'it goes in here', nodes: []
    });
  };

  $scope.editQuestion = function(question){
    Question.setSelectedQuestion(question);
  };

  $scope.isSelected = function(question) {
    return Question.isSelectedQuestion(question);
  };
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/pZkBv/

If you wanted, you could build up a richer data model using JavaScript OOP principles; for example, you could have `Question` instances with methods for manipulating the questions, which themselves live inside an instance of `QuestionContainer` (or `Survey` or `Test` or whatever).

Comment: you sir are my hero. That was one of the best answers I have ever received on stackoverflow. I really appreciate it!

Comment: So glad to have helped! Please feel free to [ping me](http://brandontilley.com/contact.html) if you have additional questions.